# How to open a pop-up window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a donations website.  The particular web page works by allowing the user to enter a monetary value in a textbox and clicking on the button 'Donate Now' to perform the transaction.

What I would like to do is to bring up a pop-up window with an error message if the user enters an invalid value in the textbox.  How can this be done?

Comment: I would like to display a pop-up window after the button click.  I searched all over the internet and on forums, but couldn't understand the code.  Can you display a pop-up window by using C#, just like in Windows applications?

Comment: On the web you'd typically show a validation message next to the input.  Most often you'd have client-side validation which is handled in JavaScript.  ASP.NET includes hooks to enable this client-side validation via configuration and the use of validation elements.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP.NET C# - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the `asp:RequiredFieldValidator`, `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` and `asp:ValidationSummary` features that asp.net provides?

**Edit**

Here is an example of a textbox which is only allowed to containt values on the form "xx-0000" (two letters, a '-', and then four digits). This is ensured by the `RegularExpressionValidator` and the `ValidationSummary` shows an popup with the error message if the textbox not containts a valid value.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtContent" /><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOk" Text="OK" OnClick="btnOk_Click" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="txtContentValidator" ControlToValidate="txtContent" ValidationExpression="^[a-z]{2}-[0-9]{4}$" ErrorMessage="Not in the correct format" Display="Static" Text="*" />
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="validationSummary" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
```

Comment: Not exactly :s  I am quite a newbie when it comes to web programming.

Comment: Thank you :)  It worked.  Is there a way to change the window name please?

Comment: The ValidationSummary has a property called `HeaderText` but it's not a "real" header text. If you want a very customized popup i think you need to look at asp.net ajax and the modual popup window. The ajax framework encapsulate javascript code in .net controls - http://www.asp.net/ajax

Comment: Thank you so much :)  You have helped a lot :)

Comment: maybe it will be possible to change some of the design by adding a cssclass, try search for "asp.net validationsummary css style" on google, you might find something :)